# SD card no longer showing in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, sd-card

I have an micro SD card that used to work fine and I stored many files on it.   It is a SanDisk Ultra 200GB card, and I use the BaseQi adaptor to put it in my Macbook Pro (running Catalina, 10.15.7).  For a long time this has worked fine.

But now the SD card is not showing up on my system.  All the online guides I find say to use Disk Utility to check or repair it, but the SD card is not showing up in Disk Utility either. I have tried unplugging & plugging the card back in, I have tried rebooting the Mac, no effect.  Visual inspection shows no damage to the SD card or the adaptor (it's just been sitting in my computer for a couple years).

What to do?

PS- If I go to "About this Mac" and choose "System Report", I get the following for "Card Reader":

```
Built in SD Card Reader:

  Vendor ID:    0x05ac
  Product ID:   0x8406
  Revision: 3.00
  Serial Number:    820
```

Comment: It sounds like either the SD card or the adapter has failed. Do you have another card to try? Another reader? Maybe another computer to try both with?

Comment: TBH, an SD card, micro or otherwise, I consider an ephemeral storage medium, subject to malfunctions and outright non-reversible failure without warning. A static jolt or a stray gamma ray is all it takes to zap one. It needs to be backed up like any other disk, and like any storage medium, needs to be physically replaced every so often. I use SD cards in my 'old' digital camera, and in my car's audio system to hold music files. That's it. After being burned one too many times with cards that suddenly failed without warning, I don't consider them reliable in the long-term. Sorry for your loss.